# Type mismatch - what is returning Unit type?

Tags: scala

```
var v1  = 1
v1 = if(v1 != 0) 0;
println(v1)
```

I get an error like this.

```
[error] /Users/hoge/project/hello.scala:62: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: Int
[error]         v1 = if(v1 != 0) 0;
[error]              ^
```

So, what is returning `Unit` type? Is it the "if" expression? I expect the program to print "0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this type error because Scala's powerful type system has caught a corner case that you've forgotten about. Let's go through each line carefully.

```
scala> var v1 = 1
v1: Int = 1
```

here we've declared a `var` called `v1`, with type `Int`.

```
scala> v1 = if (v1 != 0) 0;
error: type mismatch;
found    : Unit
required : Int
    v1 = if (v1 != 0) 0
```

Uh oh, we get a type error. We're trying to assign the result of `if (v1 != 0) 0` to `v1` so the type of the `if` expression had better be `Int` (remember, `v1: Int`). But what will happen if `v1 == 0`, ie. the implicit `else` branch is taken instead?

Scala defaults the result of the `else` branch to `Unit`, so in this case it will return `Unit`. Obviously we can't assign `Unit` to a value of type `Int`, so the compiler rightfully complains.

To fix this error, either fill in the missing `else` branch with a default `Int` value, or move the assignment of `v1` inside the branch like so `if (v1 != 0) v1 = 0`.

Comment: Make sense! "Scala defaults the result of the else branch to Unit"

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you use 
`v1 = if(v1 != 0) 0;` if the condition is not met it is still trying to assign `v1` to the expression. Try changing the code to

`if(v1 != 0) v1 = 0;`

`Unit` in scala is kind of like `void` in java.

Comment: Thanks:) In my understand, The If expression return some value in Scala. So I expect `if(v1 != 0) 0;` should be return `0` right?

Comment: BTW, this is worked.

    var v1 = 1
    val v2 = if(v1 != 0) 0;

Comment: This still presents the same problem. v2 could be either 0 or Unit because you don't have an else clause. See cdk's answer

Comment: I got it. `val v2 = if(v1 != 0) 0;` return `AnyVal`, but I got `Int` when `val v4 = if(v1 != 0) 0 else 1;` as you said.